# Moving increments into condition checks?

Tags: performance, c

I am reading the second edition of the C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie. In it, the authors introduce things like:

```
void strcpy(char *s, char*t) {
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```

on page 106, and follow it with "Although this may seem cryptic at first sight, the notational convenience is considerable, and the idiom should be mastered because you will see it frequently in C programs". Which I could agree with if being idiomatic or convenient were the only goals of a program. However, I'm left wondering why programmers would standardize on moving all those operations into the conditional. I would prefer to write

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t) {
    while(*t) {
        *s = *t;
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }
}
```

. So, why are the authors recommending this terse, cryptic, syntax? I tried to answer this on my own using compiler explorer.

I wrote two functions [`terse(...)`](https://godbolt.org/z/1TGa6aMYG) and [`not_terse(...)`](https://godbolt.org/z/bnxnxeoa7). Then, I reviewed the assembly with `-O3` and, sure enough the terse condition compiles to less instructions, but is that really it; are there other reasons this is recommended? Please help me understand the motivations for the authors statements and if this or additional benefits are the actual motivation as I have trouble seeing the notational convenience as much of a benefit.

Comment: The referenced book was published in 1978 and second edition 1988. Quite a few years passed since and modern recommendations may not match those given 30+ years ago.

Comment: You are not asking for a review of your own code here which can make this question off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

**First**: those two code samples are not actually identical functionally.

In terse, the memory address at s is set to t and then the value at s is evaluated to determine if it's the null terminator. In not_terse the value at t is evaluated and then, only if it's not the null terminator the value is copied. The difference is, terse will copy the null terminator whereas not_terse will exit the loop before copying the null terminator.

We could make the functionality identical by storing the value at s in a variable after setting it and only evaluating it after the copy:

```
void strcpy(char * s, char * t)
{
    char val = 1;
    while(val)
    {
        val = *s = *t;
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }
}
```

Which you'll see produces identical assembly code to terse: https://godbolt.org/z/Gb97GWG4f

But all this is somewhat irrelevant to the more important **Second** point which is that you're programming in C, not Assembly. You should not primarily base your decisions on how to program by what the generated Assembly code looks like. Instead, readability and maintainability should be your first concern.

The terse example is more readable to people with a good grasp of C. It might look a bit unintuitive at first, but when you get used to seeing the incrementing operator used inside of a statement and conditional checks on assignments it's very easy to follow that loop. By contrast, splitting it up forces you to try to understand each part independently. More verbose isn't always more clear.

Some of this does come down to a matter of taste, and it's not unreasonable to program in one way as a beginner and adjust your style as you become more experienced.

Comment: Re: *the memory address at s is set to t * ====> Pointers are not exchanged. The memory pointed to by `t` is copied to the memory pointed to by `s`.

Comment: Thank you for showing the lack of functional equivalence. I'm glad to see they compile to the same assembly when equivalent. Your explanation of the second point helps me understand the authors reasoning about "notational convenience".

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thank you for contributing. Note that the question was not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because the OP did not write the code. [_"For moral, practical, and legal reasons, we are only able to review code that you wrote or code that you maintain"_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654/120114) [Please refrain from answering questions that are likely to get closed.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/35991)